# Does enclosing an arbitrary variable in single quotes prevent eval() from executing code?

Tags: php, eval

I'm trying to demonstrate the dangers of using `eval()` in PHP to my coworkers.

In a piece of code I found something like (this is very simplified):

```
<?php

$i        = 0;
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'arg') !== false) {
        eval('$data' . $i . '=$value;');
        $i++;
    }
}
```

And of course I told them this should be rewritten as

```
<?php
$i=0;
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'arg') !== false) {
        $varname  = 'data' . $i;
        $$varname = $value;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

More so, that they should just use an associative array for this.

However, I haven't been able to make a real demonstration of why is this usage of eval prone to arbitrary code execution. It seems that enclosing the variable in single quotes does not execute the code.

I tried to show them something like:

```
http://localhost/eval.php?arg=var_dump($_ENV);&arg2=phpinfo():
```

And it seems parameters are sanitized instead of executed, so the array gets populated with harmless strings.

So, even if everybody agrees that eval is evil, **is it correct to assume that enclosing an arbitrary input in single quotes would stop it from ejecuting**?

Comment: I actually think this eval code might be safe because they aren't actually evaluating any user input, they are just performing an assignment.  It's just a very strange thing to see something written this way.  Regardless of the user input, the eval will always be `$data0 = $value;` and so on.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that there are cases where eval can be dangerous and there are rarely situations where it is required. It makes sense to avoid it when ever possible so you dont get too comfy with it and so that you learn to work things out correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in PHP [single quotes are different from double quotes](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) in that variables are not automatically substituted in string literals. In your example this makes the eval() (comparatively) safe because you're referencing $value, which is a string variable provided by your foreach. You're literally executing in every case:

```
$data0 = $value;
```

Which should be reasonably safe since the attacker can't specify what's being eval'd. If you used double quotes the string would be substituted BEFORE the eval() which would cause the malicious code to run. This doesn't make eval() safe, but it does work for this example.

Here's your example re-written with single quotes that would cause malicious code to run:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'arg') !== false) {
        (eval('$data' . $i . '=' . $value . ';'));
        $i++;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Yup, figured the same. You can also do something like `eval("\$data$i = \$value;");` so dollar signs are escaped and just the index `$i` is evaluated. I know about double quote replacements, but I was convinced I could demonstrate code injection nowadays. Thanks for your answer!